# Why do I get an error when trying to create this endless selenium loop?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with the following selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options=Options()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

i = 0
while True:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

    i = i + 1
```

The idea is that the chrome browser opens and closes in an endless loop. When I run it I get a 'max retry error'. How can I solve this issue?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the very first time `driver.quit()` gets executed, it will kill the browser instance. And for the 2nd iteration, the first line that has to be executed will be `driver.get("https://www.google.com/")`, now since driver object has been killed in the first iteration so the driver is null for the second iteration. Resulting in

```
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001D12A2671C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=57911): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/eedcbdf06a0db68d2b4b6e9bc76b5167/url (Caused by NewConne
```

to solve this,

**Solution:** you should create a driver instance for each iteration.

```
i = 0
while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for solving the problem.